# What is -ms-clear equivalent in WebKit and Mozilla?

Tags: css, html, webkit, mozilla, textinput

As shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh465498

Do Mozilla and Webkit have equivalent options? The clear button on text inputs is good for touch screen apps. I don't want any JavaScript workarounds and an easy CSS fix would be very helpful.

I already know this is possible with JavaScript, but IE 10 has an inbuilt solution for displaying clear button, and I'm wondering if any other browsers have similar options?

Comment: have provided my jQuery plugin link in answer - which pretty much does the same in all browsers

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is No.

There is no way to use CSS to generate a button that will clear the contents of an input without the use of JavaScript.

The clear button is built in functionality to IE10. `-ms-clear` is not what generates it, but simply a way to target it for styling.

I should mention though, that the `<input type=search>​` field in Chrome will give you a clear button as well, but not on normal `<input type=text>​` fields.

Answer (score 3):

Was looking for same issue so I made a jQuery plugin ([TextClear](http://plugins.jquery.com/textClear/)) to offer the same feature : 
here is the download [link](http://exexzian.github.io/TextClear/)

---

and about trick behind this:

- set background image on input text field and position it to the right corner like

> ```
> {
>   background-image: url('imagesUrl');
>   background-repeat: no-repeat;
>   background-position: right center;
>   background-size: 10% 90%;
>   padding-right: 1%;
> }
> ```

- And then handling click event on it by mapping its position (you can check the source code as well for detailed logic)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot actually do this using css..

But you can user jQuery, and its simple. All you gotto do is this...

HTML code:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
<input type.... />
<input type.... />
<input type.... />
<input type="button" id="clear" name="clear" />
</form>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$("#clear").click(function(){
     $("#myform").reset();
});
```

And this will work.. But the form tag is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Y U NO like Javascript? Look how easy jQuery makes this process:

**Markup**

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <button>X</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("form").on("click", "button", function() {
    $("input").val("");
    return false;
});​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QyE92/

With CSS, you can style the button and position it appropriately to mimic the "x" in the metro interface almost exactly.

Comment: I know its possible with JavaScript and I already have solution for that, IE 10 shows close button by default, I am wondering if any other browsers will come with similar solution or already have it.